# mysql query work on phpmyadmin but not work on mysqli

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I have a Query That work in phpmyadmin but not work on php (`mysqli`)

where is the problem ?

Query:

```
  INSERT INTO `SepidarSoft_Portal`.`Archive_Media` SET `CTime`='1364135670',`UTime`='1364135670',`PID`='',`State`='1',`Sequence`='0',`Subject`='Hojom Marg ( www.Parstafrih.ir )',`Text`='',`Description`='',`Definition`='',`KeyWord`='',`ETag`='',`Access`='',`LinkToPage`='',`Attachment`='[{\"Name\":null,\"Kind\":null,\"Size\":false,\"Address\":\"27\",\"More\":{\"Original\":1}}]',`STime`='0',`ETime`='0';

  SET @LAST_ID:=LAST_INSERT_ID();

  INSERT INTO `SepidarSoft_Portal`.`Archive_Media_MoreInfo`  (`id`,`Key`,`Value`) VALUES (@LAST_ID,'Instrumental','1'),(@LAST_ID,'KindFile','صوتی'),(@LAST_ID,'Genre','نغمه'),(@LAST_ID,'SName','Amir Tajik ( www.Parstafrih.ir )'),(@LAST_ID,'Events','[[\"\"]]'),(@LAST_ID,'Album','( www.Parstafrih.ir )'),(@LAST_ID,'Composer',''),(@LAST_ID,'Adjustment',''),(@LAST_ID,'Subtitle','[object HTMLInputElement]'),(@LAST_ID,'Release','');
```

Error:

```
  #1064 -You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @LAST_ID:=LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

1) I use php `mysqli_multi_query` for this

Comment: Are you inserting into mysql a possible `'`?

Comment: @phpNoOb no this is the export of query insert by `\'`

Comment: I do not see why someone downvoted this question!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is simple.

Backticks ( ` ) are used to execute commands in php. That's why you're being given a syntax error. Replace them with single or double quotes within your mysqli functions.

Kindly read the following document and you should be sorted :)

[Backticks on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

Comment: From your link `Note: Unlike some other languages, backticks cannot be used within double-quoted strings.` So `mysqli_multi_query("INSERT INTO \`SepidarSoft_Portal\`.\`Archive_Media\` SET ...")` will not execute a command. It is acceptable to use backticks when your table and/or column name is a MySQL reserved word. see also - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11321508/689579

Comment: Also, your suggestion to use `single or double quotes within your mysqli functions` will not work if their MySQL is not in [ANSI mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html) using [ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes), which [MySQL by default has no special modes enabled](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-sql-modes.html#qandaitem-B-3-1-7).